# ISP configured Dynamic IP is different from what websites see when I access them

Tags: networking, router, modem, dynamic-ip

We switched our internet connection and now something wired is going on.

I am using a TP Link Archer 1600 modem.

The ISP asked me to set connection type as "Dynamic IP" under EWAN settings. Internet is working just fine.

But my modem shows the below IP is assigned by the ISP:

[image]

But when I use the external website to find my public IP I get a different one:

[image]

My router is configured to update no-ip.org with my current IP so that I can access my home network from anywhere in the world through dynamic IP. But no IP registers 119.18.3.17 (the one reported by google when I searched fo "my IP").

When I try accessing my home network through this IP I am not able to connect. However, when I try to access my home network from outside using the IP in my first screenshot, it works just fine.

Why is the ISP assigned IP different from the IP other websites see when I access them? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `100.64.0.0/10` subnet is [Shared address space](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)
Not a valid public IP address, if you try to connect to that address from the same ISP it might work, but it is not globally routable.

The reason for this is the IPv4 shortage, so this `100.` subnet is now a special case which ISPs can use internally and do NAT on, that way reducing number of IPv4 addresses they need.

You should contact your ISP and see how you would go about getting a globally routable public IP. (many still make this option available, if not consider a change of ISP)

Comment: Thank you @NiKiZe. I talked to my ISP and they were kind enough to take me out of CGNat and map the IP address directly. My IP is still dynamic, but it works for my purpose. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP is using Carrier Grade NAT. You can't fix it except by paying for a dedicated ip address.

Comment: Thank you @joeqwerty. I talked to my ISP and they were kind enough to take me out of CGNat and map the IP address directly. My IP is still dynamic, but it works for my purpose.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help...